# Paragraph indent in textarea with CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, css, textarea

You have some web-site with text area in it, example I'm using - http://writer.bighugelabs.com, it is a really neat tool to write texts in, but I have one issue with it - paragraphs in textarea are not indented from each other.

So is it possible to overwrite some CSS properties to get paragraph indent when visiting this site using StyleBot for Chrome as example and what properties? If not possible, then would it be possible with similar extension which can apply custom JS on the page?

Please advice, I've searched for the topic, but didn't quite find the information. I tried to override p margin and padding properties, but with no success as I understand textarea has just a raw text.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can start by inspecting the markup and css with your development tools and go from there. You can even override css values on the spot and see them change live. What have you tried?

Comment: The thing is, it is not my site and I just want to change how it looks. When I look in the code, I see that there is a textarea with custom class and that's it. Inside textarea text is not broke down by p tags, so it seems I can't use p properties to get paragraph indent. So i'm lost here.

Comment: As a side remark - I'm a bit geeky, but I'm by no means specialist in  webdev/css/js, so look at it from this perspective. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the text area on the page is really an HTML `textarea`, you cannot style paragraphs inside it in CSS. There no paragraphs as elements there, just plain text, which may contain line breaks. Modern pages with embedded editor utilities tend to use editable `div` elements instead of `textarea` elements, which are rather inflexible.

You could simulate paragraph indents using JavaScript code that inserts one or two no-break spaces after each line break.